# Using dict values to count iterations over a list to insert

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
import random
from itertools import repeat

races_per_season = {
    '2015' : "19",
    '2016' : "21",
    '20116' : "21",
    '2017' : "20",
    '2018' : "21",
    '2019' : "21",
    '2020' : "17",
    '2021' : "16"
}

tmp_list = list(repeat(random.sample(range(80),10), 156))
total_races = 0
for k,v in races_per_season.items(): 
    while total_races < int(v):
        tmp_list[total_races].insert(1, k)
        total_races += 1
        break # inserting breaks here and below, somewhat works, but only gives me the first year throughout the list
    break


for x in tmp_list:
    print(x)
```

I am trying to use the dict values to iterate over a list of list and insert the key into the list at index 1. However, no matter how I try, it seems to iterate and insert all keys into the list then moves on to the next...

This is the result I am seeing.... however by adding the breaks above, this continues throughout the list of 156 lists.. and doesn't change at list 19

```
[[29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015',  56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015',  56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73]]
```

but my desired result is the following.

```
[[29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73],
 [29, '2015', 56, 39, 31, 25, 37, 5, 16, 8, 73]...
```

and continuing with '2015' 19 times, then inserting '2016' into the following 21 etc.. When I just print out the k,v pairs it works as I want it to, but I can't somehow convert that into a list.  All values in the dict sum to the value of the len(tmp_list) **156**

**ANY** help would be more than appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Note that the length of all values in the dict, i.e. `sum([int(v) for v in races_per_season.values()])`, this is 156 - same as len(tmp_list). If possible might want to clarify that in the post.

Comment: @BeerHuntor can you explain the logic, how you updating the list, Your current logic seems to have a problem

Comment: @deadshot I have scraped data from a website, and sorted it into a list of lists.  To insert into a DataFrame at a future date, however, as the page was awkward to scrape, due to span rows, I've had to do 2 list - one for odd rows, one for even.. this is the product of the odd rows.  I am trying to insert a year into the list according to the dict key for however many races that season.. so 2015 for the first 19 lists and so on.

Comment: IIUC `tmp_list[total_races][0] = k` this will give your expected output

Comment: that would replace index 0.. would it not?  I want to insert it

Comment: @BeerHuntor try this `tmp_list[total_races][0] = k if len(str(tmp_list[total_races][0])) == 4 else tmp_list[total_races].insert(0, k)`

Comment: @deadshot my code above gives the same effect as your solution, but instead of giving me the value '2016' for some reason as yours does, it gives me '2015' throughout the list.. Your second solution, gives me 18 inserts of 2015 and 3 of 2016

Comment: @BeerHuntor your question is not clear

Comment: @deadshot I'm not sure how more clearly I can make it.. I want to insert the key of '2015' from races_per_season into index 1 of each list value times, then repeat with the next key value pair ... So the first 19 list show 2015 at index 1, the next 21 show 2016, next 21 show 20116 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
import random
from itertools import repeat

races_per_season = {
    '2015' : "19",
    '2016' : "21",
    '20116' : "21",
    '2017' : "20",
    '2018' : "21",
    '2019' : "21",
    '2020' : "17",
    '2021' : "16"
}
# this line to create 156 lists that are not sharing the same reference
tmp_list = [list(arr) for arr in repeat(random.sample(range(80),10), 156)]
i = 0
for k,v in races_per_season.items():
    total_races = 0
    while total_races < int(v):
        tmp_list[i].insert(0, k)
        tmp_list[i].insert(0, int(v))
        total_races += 1
        i+=1

for x in tmp_list:
    print(x)
```

Comment: This solution has the correct effect, only all into one list before continuing.

Comment: didn't get "only all into one list before continuing.".  However, if it's working with you accept the answer, please

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, seems to be working for me at least.

```py
import random
from itertools import repeat

races_per_season = {
    '2015' : "19",
    '2016' : "21",
    '20116' : "21",
    '2017' : "20",
    '2018' : "21",
    '2019' : "21",
    '2020' : "17",
    '2021' : "16"
}

tmp_list = list(repeat(random.sample(range(80), 10), 156))

seasons = [season for season, races in races_per_season.items()
           for i in range(int(races))]

tmp_list = [[L[0], seasons[i], *L[1:]] for i, L in enumerate(tmp_list)]

for x in tmp_list:
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
[44, '2015', 18, 33, 30, 54, 22, 53, 19, 4, 68]
...repeated 18 times
[44, '2016', 18, 33, 30, 54, 22, 53, 19, 4, 68]
...repeated 20 times
...
```

#### Explanation

In the first part of above approach, we use use two `list` comprehensions to build a `years` variable. The first comprehension iterates over key-value pairs in the dictionary, and the second one iterates over all numbers `0...n-1` in the value for each key - for example, with key '2015' we have `n=19`.

To explain the following syntax used:

```
[L[0], seasons[i], *L[1:]]
```

This basically says:

1. create a new list with the first element in `L`, which is a sub-list within `tmp_list`
2. add the season we're iterating over as the second element
3. The `[1:]` says, get me all the elements in the sub-list except for the first element. The star `*` operator unpacks that result again, so we don't end up with a list within each list for example.

Comment: Perfect solution thank you.  Would it be possible to explain the syntax specifically [[tmp_list[i][0], k, *tmp_list[i][1:]  this is the only part I am not sure with, as never come across this before in this way

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. By the way, what was the issue with the other solution? It seems to me like it gives the same output.

Comment: @BeerHuntor yep, I can update teh answer with a brief explanation of that syntax.

Comment: For me using the list I have already, gives me everything in one list, then continues leaving each list with a length of 322.. which is not what I intended.. I think he edited it since, but when I initially tested it, it put all 156 inserts into 1 list, then moved onto the next.. Not sure if it was the way he was doing the list, but as my list is already generated, I cant use his list the way he made it... and perfect thank you

Comment: upon further inspection this solution doesn't work. It is actually duplicating lists throughout by overwriting other lists.  https://pastebin.com/ji0YP05i this is the correct list before the solution..  https://pastebin.com/LkQh1P0h and this is the list after the solution.. for an example CTL + F '168' in both.

Comment: @BeerHuntor can you try now? I updated to use a slightly different approach. This one shouldn't modify the same indexes within `tmp_list`.

Comment: Scratch that,  my lists must of been messed up.  A clean fresh start seemed to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a separate list for years, then add year to each list

```
years = [k  for k, v in races_per_season.items() for i in range(int(v))]

res = [[years[idx]] + lst for idx, lst in enumerate(tmp_list)]
print(res)
```